# What is the difference between Node *head versus Node **head?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, structure, singly-linked-list

I am writing a C code to find the middle of linked list. I understood the logic but was unable to figure out how pointers are being used. What is the difference in the way `Node *head` and `Node** head_ref` work?

```
void middle(struct Node *head) ;

void push(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data) ;
```

Comment: One points to data, the other points to a pointer.

Comment: In the second function you need to pass a reference to the pointer pointing to the head of the list, because the function modify the location of the head. C pass parameters always by value, so if you simply pass a pointer, you don't get it's new value after returning from the function.

Comment: An alternative would be to pass `struct Node *head` but return `struct Node *` instead of void. That way you can return the pointer to the new head.

Answer (score 7):

In the first function header, `*head` is a pointer to a node object which is allocated somewhere in memory:

```
void middle(struct Node *head);
              _____________________
             |                     |
   *head --> |     Node object     |
             | [val=1][*next=NULL] |
             |_____________________|
```

while in the second function header, `**head_ref` is a pointer to a pointer to a node object somewhere in memory:

```
void push(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data); 
              _____________________
             |                     |
   *head --> |     Node object     |
     ^       | [val=1][*next=NULL] |
     |       |_____________________|
     |    
 **head_ref
```

This is another layer of indirection. Why is the second construct necessary? Well, if I want to modify something allocated outside of my function scope, I need a pointer to its memory location. In the first example, I can dereference the `*head` pointer (with `head->`) to access the underlying `Node` object in memory and make modifications to it or access its properties.

Taking this logic to the next level of indirection, if I want to push a new `Node` object onto the front of the list to make it the new head, I need to modify the `head` pointer itself. Just as when I wanted to manipulate the `Node` object with a pointer, now I need a pointer to `*head` (which simply happens to be a pointer rather than a `Node` object) in order to modify it.

Here's the contents of `push` and a before/after function call:

```
void push(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data) {
    Node *new_head = malloc(sizeof(Node)); // allocate memory for the new head node
    new_head->data = new_data;             // set its value

    new_head->next = *head_ref;            // make it point to the 
                                           // old head pointer

    *head_ref = new_head;                  // make it the new head by modifying
                                           // the old head pointer directly
}
```

```
/* Before push */
              _____________________
             |                     |
   *head --> |     Node object     |
     ^       | [val=1][*next=NULL] |
     |       |_____________________|
     |    
 **head_ref
```

```
/* After calling push(&head, 2);
 *                    ^
 *                   `&` operator gets the memory address of `head`, 
 *                       which is a pointer.
 */

              _________________      _____________________
             |                 |    |                     |
   *head --> |   Node object   |    |      Node object    |
     ^       | [val=2] [*next]----->| [val=1][*next=NULL] |
     |       |_________________|    |_____________________|
     |    
 **head_ref
```

Here's a full example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

void push(Node** head_ref, int new_data) {
    Node *new_head = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    new_head->data = new_data;
    new_head->next = *head_ref;
    *head_ref = new_head; 
}

void print(Node *head) {
    while (head) {
        printf("%d->", head->data);
        head = head->next;
    }

    puts("NULL");
}

void free_list(Node *head) {
    while (head) {
        Node *tmp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
}

int main() {
    Node *head = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    head->next = NULL;
    head->data = 1;
    printf("Before push:\n");
    print(head);
    push(&head, 2);
    printf("\nAfter push:\n");
    print(head);
    free_list(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Before push:
1->NULL

After push:
2->1->NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

struct Node *head   - > Here the pointer head is a pointer to the head of the Linked List. Head is a pointer which can point to a node structure.

eg.

If you have a linked list like this :- 
          ____      ____      _____
         |_1__|--->|_2__|--->|_3__|--->.......
address-  1000      1004      1008

Your Node *head  will be a pointer variable holding the address of the node with value 1(address of the head node which is the node storing the value 1).
Content of head=1000

struct Node **head_ref  -> here the head_ref is the pointer to the pointer of the start of the linked list.

eg.

If you have a linked list like this :- 
          ____      ____      _____
         |_1__|--->|_2__|--->|_3__|--->.......
address-  1000      1004      1008
           |
         *head
address-  5050
           |
         **head

Your Node *head  will be a pointer variable holding the address of the node with value 1(address of the head node which is the node storing the value 1).
Content of head=1000
Content of **head_ref will be the address of the head pointer i.e, 5050.

**head_ref is used for indirect reference.