# C - linked list reverse recursively: why use double pointer?

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list, reverse

I understand the logic when the `struct Node *head` is a global variable.

However, when I do the reverse using `struct Node *head` as a local variable in `main()`, I have to use double-pointer and pointer of `Head`, and I don't understand where exactly I have to place them.

```
void Reverse(struct Node *Head, struct Node **headpointer) {
    struct Node *first;
    // when the list is empty
    if (Head == NULL)
        return;

    first = Head;
    // when there is one node left
    if (first->next == NULL) {
        *headpointer = first;
        return;
    }

    Reverse(first->next, headpointer);

    first->next->next = first;
    first->next = NULL;
}
```

I am unclear why I have to use...

```
first = Head;
*headpointer = first;
```

why can't I just use

```
Head = first?
```

Also, if `first = Head` line in front of the recursive function call `Reverse(first->next, headpointer)`, don't the `first->next` value also equal to `Head` which points to the `first` node?

Is there any good logical diagram/pic/explanation/examples that can explain this difference?

Comment: You need a recursive function, but are you constrained to the given signature for it? That is, could you use different arguments and/or return value?

Comment: Using a global variable for a head pointer makes the linked list almost useless. You can only ever have one list.

Comment: What would `Head = first;` accomplish? If `first` has been set to `Head`, then the assignment does nothing, and if it hasn't then the assignment causes UB.

Comment: When you pass a pointer to a function, the function receives a *Copy Of* the pointer with a very different address, but holding the same pointed-to address as its value. When you reverse a list, you must change the address of the head pointer so it now holds the last node as its value. At this point you have two options (1) make the return type for your reverse function a pointer-to-node so you can return the updated head address and assign the new value to head back in the caller, or (2) pass a pointer-to-pointer so the address of head is passed and can be updated within your function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Node \*head versus Node \*\*head?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55654934/what-is-the-difference-between-node-head-versus-node-head)

Answer (score 1):

> I am unclear why I have to use... `first = Head`

Actually, the `first` variable isn't needed in this code at all. It is just a copy of `Head`, so to simplify you can just replace the variable with `Head`. Everything will work the same without it:

```
if (Head == NULL)
  return;

if (Head->next == NULL) {
  *headpointer = Head;
  return;
}

Reverse(Head->next, headpointer);

Head->next->next = Head;
Head->next = NULL;
```

> I am unclear why I have to use... `*headpointer = Head`

The `Head` variable is the pointer to the head of the list you want to reverse, and the function stores the head of the newly reversed list into `*headpointer`. It does this because `Head` is just a copy of the pointer that was passed in to the `Reverse()` function, so updating its value won't change the original pointer; that's why a separate double pointer variable is used.

> why can't I just use `Head = first`?

`Head` is a copy of the pointer that was passed to the function. Updating the `Head` pointer will not update the original list pointer that you passed in. Also, as I said before, `Head` is the same as `first`, so an assignment like that does nothing.

> Also, if `first = Head` line in front of the recursive function call `Reverse(first->next, headpointer)`, don't the `first->next` value also equal to `Head` which points to the `first` node?

`first->next` (or `Head->next`) is just the next node in the list. The purpose of the function call is to reverse the rest of the list first, and then place `Head` (or `first`) at the end of the list (which is what the last two lines do).

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the function signature was like this:

```c
void Reverse(struct Node* Head, struct Node* headpointer) {
```

And you call it like this

```c
Reverse(myList);
```

`myList` is just an address to a Node, for example `0x1234`. So it's equivalent to do:

```c
Reverse(0x1234);
```

The address is copied to a new variable `headpointer`. When we modify `headpointer` we are modifying a *local* variable, not the `myList` we passed.

It's like if we did this:

```c
struct Node* myList = 0x1234;
struct Node* headpointer = myList;
headpointer = 0xABCD;
// at this point myList is still 0x1234
```

So after the function returns, `myList` is still equal to `0x1234`. That's not what we want because is should now point to the last node.

So how do we allow, the function to modify `myList`? We have to tell the function "hey, here's the address where you have to write to".

In C, in order to take the address of something we use the '&' operator:

```c
Reverse(&myList);
```

And we must change the signature of the function accordingly:

```c
void Reverse(struct Node* Head, struct Node** headpointer) {
```

Now `headpointer` is an address to an address to a `Node`. Or, as we say in C, a pointer to a pointer to a `Node`.

Here's a final example that can help understand.

```c
struct Node* myList = 0x1234;
struct Node** headpointer = &myList; // now headpointer points to myList
*headpointer = 0xABCD;
// at this point myList is still 0xABCD
// we haven't changed headpointer, but the thing headpointer is pointing to!
```

Answer (score 0):

It *is* necessary to be able to return the *updated* `head` node, but this *could* be done with a return value in lieu of using a double pointer.

Also, I believe that the function *needs* to be passed a pointer to the *previous* node so it can set that as the *new* `next` pointer.

So, I think your function would need *three* arguments (e.g.) `cur`, `prev`, `headpointer`.

If we return the `head` pointer, we can reduce this to *two*.

---

Here's a version that does that.

I've tried to annotate it as much as possible. I've added debug `printf` and some cross checking [which I used to debug it myself].

*If* you *need* to have a double pointer, this example *could* be adapted without too much trouble.

```
// revlist -- reverse singly linked list recursively

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    struct node *next;
    int data;
#ifdef CHECK
    int visited;                    // 1=node visited (check for looped list)
#endif
} Node;

#ifdef DEBUG
int dbglvl;                         // nesting level -- debug only
#endif

int
prt(Node *node)
{
    int data;

    if (node != NULL)
        data = node->data;
    else
        data = -1;

    return data;
}

#ifdef DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt ...) \
    do { \
        printf("DBG/%d: ",dbglvl); \
        printf(_fmt); \
    } while (0)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt ...) \
    do { } while (0)
#endif

// reverse -- recursively reverse list
// RETURNS: pointer to head of reversed list
Node *
reverse(Node *cur,Node *prev)
// cur -- pointer to current node
// prev -- pointer to previous node
{
    Node *next;
    Node *head = NULL;

    do {
        // empty list
        if (cur == NULL)
            break;

        next = cur->next;

        dbgprt("BEG cur=%d prev=%d next=%d\n",
            prt(cur),prt(prev),prt(next));

        // at end of list -- set new head from tail node
        if (next == NULL) {
            head = cur;
            head->next = prev;
            dbgprt("SETHEAD head=%d head->next=%d\n",
                prt(head),prt(head->next));
            break;
        }

#ifdef DEBUG
        ++dbglvl;
#endif
        // process the next node and give the current node as the previous one
        head = reverse(next,cur);
#ifdef DEBUG
        --dbglvl;
#endif

        // set the link pointer to the previous node
        cur->next = prev;
        dbgprt("POST cur->next=%d\n",prt(cur->next));
    } while (0);

    dbgprt("EXIT head=%d\n",prt(head));

    return head;
}

// addnode -- add node to tail of list
Node *
addnode(Node *head,int data)
{
    Node *newnode = malloc(sizeof(*newnode));
    Node *cur;
    Node *prev;

    newnode->next = NULL;
    newnode->data = data;
#ifdef CHECK
    newnode->visited = 0;
#endif

    // find the tail of the list
    prev = NULL;
    for (cur = head;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next)
        prev = cur;

    // add new node to list
    if (prev != NULL)
        prev->next = newnode;
    else
        head = newnode;

    return head;
}

// list_print -- print list
void
list_print(Node *head,const char *reason)
{
    Node *cur;

    printf("%s:",reason);

    for (cur = head;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next) {
        printf(" %d",cur->data);
#ifdef CHECK
        if (cur->visited) {
            printf(" DUP\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        cur->visited = 1;
#endif
    }

    printf("\n");

#ifdef CHECK
    for (cur = head;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next)
        cur->visited = 0;
#endif
}

// list_destroy -- destroy the list
void
list_destroy(Node *cur)
{
    Node *next;

    for (;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next) {
        next = cur->next;
        free(cur);
    }
}

// dotest -- test reverse function
void
dotest(int max)
{
    Node *head = NULL;

#ifdef DEBUG
    dbglvl = 0;
#endif

    // create a list
    for (int idx = 1;  idx <= max;  ++idx)
        head = addnode(head,idx);

    // show the original list
    list_print(head,"Forward");

    // reverse the list
    head = reverse(head,NULL);

    // show the reversed list
    list_print(head,"Reverse");

    // destroy the test list
    list_destroy(head);
}

int
main(void)
{

    dotest(8);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's the program output:

```
Forward: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
Reverse: 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

---

Here's the program output with the debug `printf` enabled:

```
Forward: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
DBG/0: BEG cur=1 prev=-1 next=2
DBG/1: BEG cur=2 prev=1 next=3
DBG/2: BEG cur=3 prev=2 next=4
DBG/3: BEG cur=4 prev=3 next=5
DBG/4: BEG cur=5 prev=4 next=6
DBG/5: BEG cur=6 prev=5 next=7
DBG/6: BEG cur=7 prev=6 next=8
DBG/7: BEG cur=8 prev=7 next=-1
DBG/7: SETHEAD head=8 head->next=7
DBG/7: EXIT head=8
DBG/6: POST cur->next=6
DBG/6: EXIT head=8
DBG/5: POST cur->next=5
DBG/5: EXIT head=8
DBG/4: POST cur->next=4
DBG/4: EXIT head=8
DBG/3: POST cur->next=3
DBG/3: EXIT head=8
DBG/2: POST cur->next=2
DBG/2: EXIT head=8
DBG/1: POST cur->next=1
DBG/1: EXIT head=8
DBG/0: POST cur->next=-1
DBG/0: EXIT head=8
Reverse: 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```